Identify this non-American movie where a half-dressed girl in heels answers a door
The only scene I remember is: 
A girl is lying on a mattress on the floor in an empty loft during daylight. There is a knock (or bell ring) at the door and then she gets up and hurries to the door. You see she is only wearing a short top and high-heeled shoes with no pants. She opens the door to a (fully-dressed) guy, who walks in and they talk in the flat. Apparently they know each other. The girl acts naturally, even though she is half naked.
Then, another naked girl (with glasses?) walks into the living room. She is surprised to see the guy, so she tries to hide her genitals with her hands. 
I have one picture from that scene that shows the girl who opens the door and the guy. As far as I remember it is a foreign movie: French? Italian? Not sure about the language.
Does this ring a bell to someone?
Even if you just recognize the actors, so I could check in which movies they appear in.


That's Yuliya Mayarchuk in Trasgredire, (2000).  Here's a photo from the movie where she's wearing the same top.


Wow... that's awesome. nice job!

well done,...and a very quick answer. Thank you a lot.
